# Why $e^{z} ≠ 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, exponential-function, solution-verification

I want to show that $e^{z}$ is never zero.

So I solved this by contradiction

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $z = x + iy$ $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

$e^{z}$ is zero

$e^{z} = 0$

$e^{x+iy} = e^{x}(\cos({y})+i\sin({y})) = 0$

then I did $\cos({y})+i\sin({y}) =0$ therefore $\cos({y}) = \sin({y}) = 0$

and this is a contradiction.

Now I am self doubting myself why $\cos({y})$ = $\sin({y})$ = $0$ for the $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $\cos^2y+\sin^2y=1$ but $0^2+0^2=0$

Comment: A monoid morphism $f \colon G \to M$ whose target monoid $G$ is actually a group will necessarily take only images that are invertible in the target monoid $M$ (more succinctly, $\mathrm{Im}f \subseteq \mathrm{U}(M)$, where the latter is my notation for the unit group of $M$). In your particular case the exponential is a morphism between the additive group $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ and the multiplicative monoid $(\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$.

Answer (score 5):

We can't have $\cos y=\sin y=0$, because $0^2+0^2=0$, but we must have $\cos^2y+\sin^2y=1$.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way could be by exp($x+y$)=exp($x$)exp($y$) for any $x$ and $y$. Therefore for $y=-x$ you have $1=$exp($0$)$=$exp($x+(-x)$)=exp($x$)exp($-x$) and so for any $x$ you have exp($x$)$ \neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

From basic trigonometry we have

$\forall y \in \Bbb R, \; \sin^2y + \cos^2y = 1, \tag 1$

and this prohibits

$\sin y = \cos y = 0. \tag 2$

The contradiction lies in the fact that the assumption

$e^x(\cos y + i \sin y) = e^{x + iy} = e^z = 0 \tag 3$

forces (2), which is impossible.

Comment: I believe why it prohibits the (2) because there needs to be some y that make my statement true. Which it can't be because there needs to be y gives an output to be 0...which is impossible, one of them will be 0 and the other will be 1 or -1. This contradict it.